# How to strore and retrieve data with html code in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am a beignner in ROR, need some help regarding database storing and retrieving values

my controller class is `demo_controller.rb` and following is the class code..

```
class DemoController < ApplicationController
    def user

    end    
end
```

my model has a class `user.rb` and following is the class code...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password
end
```

my view named `user.html.erb` has the following code to show on browser...

```
<h1>Create User</h1>
    <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="f_name" placeholder="Enter your first Name...">
                </div>

    </div>
        </br>
    <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">last Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="l_name" placeholder="Enter your last Name...">
                </div>           
    </div>
        </br>
    <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Email address</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your Email address...">
                </div>              
    </div>
        </br>

    <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Password</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Enter your Password...">
                </div>            
    </div>
        </br> 
        </br> 
        </br>
          <button class="btn" type="submit">Add Info</button>
          <button class="btn" type="reset" >Reset</button>
```

and i have created a database that has a table name `user` and the field of the table are

```
first_name
last_name
email
password
```

and I want to store values into my database and retrieve from database to browser... but didn't find anything suitable to implement as I tried a lot of methods. please tell me how to do that.. Thanks!

Comment: Every single Rails tutorial has this information; it is what RoR is best at, and it's trivially easy. If you're having a  *specific* problem, describe it.

Comment: i tried everything and every possible way.. that i know but didn't successful.. thats why i am asking for help.

Comment: I doubt you did, or it would have worked. I'd suggest something like http://ruby.railstutorial.org/, because how to hook up forms, controllers, and the DB *is* in every beginning Rails tutorial, because doing these types of things in Rails is ridiculously easy.

Comment: one of the start points: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app and don't say you've tried everything.

Comment: See how to ask questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask then start questioning

Comment: I tried these.. but its not helping me.. what do u think i didn't tried that all... and @rmagnum2002 i didn't said that i tried all i said " i tried everything and every possible way that i know"... if i tried everything that exists then it a foolish think to put a question over here.. i though that there is something that can be helpful but didn't getting that.!

Comment: Your controller code has absolutely no processing in it whatsoever. Your HTML doesn't even have a form. You haven't stated what you've *actually* tried, what didn't work about it, etc. If you're a beginner in Rails, follow a tutorial.

Comment: @wasikhn look friend, no offense but your code looks bad.. where did you learn to put pure html code html.erb file, you have no ruby code, and even if you would do this in pure html, you don't have a form tag, empty controller.. you started with a wrong foot, if you'll expect always others to do it for you you'll never learn it.

Comment: And if you say you've tried something, show me some links or screenshot of a book where author says you should put pure html in a erb file.

Comment: I have to agree with everyone. What you're asking for is explained in every single rails tutorial, so I have to flag this question.

Comment: @wasikhn look here http://railscasts.com/ you'll find a lot of good tutorials that probably will help you to move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should select a start point of Ruby on Rails. For example , the book named 'Agile Web Development with Rails 4th Edition' is very good for beginners. It has a completed demo step by step.

For this case. You can start with a new project.

Execute the command below one by one:

```
rails new demo  
bundle install
rails g scaffold user first_name:string last_name:string email:string password:string
rake db:migrate
rails s
```

If no error occours, you will see rails created lots of files for you and start at port 3000.

access `http://localhost:3000/users` and click the 'new' link to add your user.